# Google Maps API: Blank page (No map)

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I pretty much copied the code from the tutorial:
https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3
(Of course, I made the proper changes, I guess).

Can you help me figure out why the map is not showing up?

I am using MySQL/PHP to generate [an XML output](http://firstchoicehousing.com/_api/google/maps/phpsqlajax_genxml2.php) (Similar code as the tutorial):

```
<?php
require("database.php");

function parseToXML($htmlStr) 
{ 
$xmlStr=str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace('>','&gt;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&#39;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr); 
return $xmlStr; 
} 

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server
$connection=mysql_connect ($localhost, $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
  die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Set the active MySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Select all the rows in the tbl_address table
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_address WHERE 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Start XML file, echo parent node
echo '<markers>';

// Iterate through the rows, printing XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
  echo '<marker ';
  echo 'name="' . parseToXML($row['address']) . '" ';
  echo 'address="' . parseToXML($row['address']) . '" ';
  echo 'lat="' . $row['latitude'] . '" ';
  echo 'lng="' . $row['longitude'] . '" ';
  echo 'type="USC Student Housing" ';
  echo '/>';
}

// End XML file
echo '</markers>';

?>
```

Here is [the map](http://firstchoicehousing.com/_api/google/maps/phpsqlajax_map_v3.html) (Similar code as the tutorial):

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>PHP/MySQL & Google Maps Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

    var customIcons = {
      restaurant: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      },
      bar: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      }
    };

    function load() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.026485, -118.283794),
        zoom: 14,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      });
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
      downloadUrl("http://firstchoicehousing.com/_api/google/maps/phpsqlajax_genxml2.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var name = markers[[]i].getAttribute("name");
          var address = markers[[]i].getAttribute("address");
          var type = markers[[]i].getAttribute("type");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[[]i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[[]i].getAttribute("lng")));
          var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
          var icon = customIcons[[]type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon,
            shadow: icon.shadow
          });
          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }
      });
    }

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {}

    //]]>

  </script>

  </head>

  <body onload="load()">
    <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks to @user1289347 I was able to make the map work. One last thing...how do I make this map look just like this one?: http://tiny.cc/yqg1cw (I need the list of addresses on the right side AND the tool-tip to include a url, etc)

Comment: ATTENTION!!! If you are reading this, I would like to comment that google's tutorial sample comes with several errors. Most of those are addressed here

Comment: In Google's website, the sample code [phpsqlajax_genxml.php](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/articles/phpsqlajax/phpsqlajax_genxml.php), to generate an xml data-source file has the following error: `$connection=mysql_connect (localhost, $username, $password);` the variable `localhost` should be `$localhost` (It is missing the '$' -dollar sign). Also, `$localhost` needs to be included within the file [phpsqlajax_dbinfo.php](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/articles/phpsqlajax/phpsqlajax_dbinfo.php)

Comment: As @user1289347 pointed out, the reason this code was not showing a map was because Google's sample code [phpsqlajax_map_v3.html](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/articles/phpsqlajax/phpsqlajax_map_v3.html) has the following error: `markers[[]i]` -Their markers array should be `markers[i]` (It comes with extra `[]`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The changes need to be made to every one of the syntax errors.  The full js is below.  here is a fiddle, it doesn't show the markers because I can't use ajax cross domain to get the list but you can see the map load.  http://jsfiddle.net/zvmdp/

edit
changed your code to this and it runs

```
var customIcons = {
      restaurant: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      },
      bar: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      }
    };

    function load() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.026485, -118.283794),
        zoom: 14,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      });
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
      downloadUrl("http://firstchoicehousing.com/_api/google/maps/phpsqlajax_genxml2.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
          var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
          var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
          var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
          var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon,
            shadow: icon.shadow
          });
          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }
      });
    }

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {}
```

Comment: In firefox ctrl+shift+J, in chrome F12 key and click on the console tab

Comment: take a look, I fixed your code in the scratchpad and this is what it looks like http://tctel.com/screen.jpg

Comment: one last thing...how do I make this map look just like this one: http://www.firstchoicehousing.com/leasing/properties.html (I need the list of addresses on the right side AND the tool-tip to include a url)

Comment: the tooltip is an info window, here is the documentation on how to add it https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#InfoWindows   As far as the links you would need to loop through your xml and print them in a container outside of the map, and attach javascript to the onclick or href that manipulates the map.

Comment: Cool!!! Thanks!. What about the list of addresses on the right? -I need the list's link to point to the right place on the map too...

Comment: View their source, you can see that cm_markerClicked is the function that is called when the links are clicked, and the ID passed is the ID of the marker created by your xml loop already.  So it opens the infowindow for that marker.  Copy their code as best you can, then post another question when you get stuck.